# Compressing the committed source using svn post-commit

Tags: svn

I'm using svn to check only the contents of the changed source, the changed date, etc.
As an implicit rule, I know that trunk, branch, and tag are used by default, but in my current situation, it was not necessary to do so.

Nevertheless, it was necessary to separate the original and revised versions whenever the source is newly committed, so I decided to execute the post-commit by making the tag into a general directory rather than svn.

```
#/bin/bash
  
cd /svn/tag/
FILE=`ls -l | grep ^- | wc -l`
VER=1

if [ ${FILE} = 0 ] ; then
        echo $VER
        else
        VER=$((FILE+1))
fi

cd /svn/gb/
tar -cvf gb.$VER.tar ./
mv gb.$VER.tar /svn/tag
```

```
#/bin/bash

REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
TXN_NAME="$3"

#"$REPOS"/hooks/mailer.py commit "$REPOS" $REV "$REPOS"/mailer.conf

REPOS_NAME=`echo $REPOS | awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"} {print $NF}'`
source /root/post-commit.sh $REPOS_NAME $REV
```

it's my script.

It seemed to work fine.
After the commit, the source is compressed and put into the specified folder with an appropriate name.

But when I looked at the source, it was found that the original source before the commit was compressed, not after the commit.

My guess is that since this is a post-commit, the modified source should be compressed.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
Strangely, when I newly configured the svn server, it worked normally.
It's not a perfect answer, but I'm still satisfied with it...